# Python Elementtree delete/edit a node

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am currently creating a project in python that requires xml manipulation. To manipulate the xml file, I will use Elementtree. Never worked with that module before. I used to use php, but is complety different.

I have the following xml file:

```
<myvideos>
    <video>
        <title>video1</title>
        <plot>description bla bla bla</plot>
        <duration>50</duration>
    </video>
    <video>
        <title>name2</title>
        <plot>another description bla bla bla</plot>
        <duration>37</duration>
    </video>
    <video>
        <title>another name etc</title>
        <plot>description etc...</plot>
        <duration>99</duration>
    </video>
</myvideos>
```

What I want to do is search by video title, (for exemple "name2") and then delete or edit that video entry.
Exemples:

1) Search for video with title "name2" and delete the video entry:

```
<myvideos>
    <video>
        <title>video1</title>
        <plot>description bla bla bla</plot>
        <duration>50</duration>
    </video>
    <video>
        <title>another name etc</title>
        <plot>description etc...</plot>
        <duration>99</duration>
    </video>
</myvideos>
```

2) Search for video with title "name2" and edit that entry:

```
<myvideos>
    <video>
        <title>video1</title>
        <plot>description bla bla bla</plot>
        <duration>50</duration>
    </video>
    <video>
        <title>name2renamed</title>
        <plot>edited</plot>
        <duration>9999</duration>
    </video>
    <video>
        <title>another name etc</title>
        <plot>description etc...</plot>
        <duration>99</duration>
    </video>
</myvideos>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is a question-and-answer site. Readers, such as yourself, ask questions and other readers try to answer them. I notice that your post is missing a question. Do you have a specific question to ask? (Also, you might want to review [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).)

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. I would like to ask if is possible to do that using ElementTree.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I would start by reading the ElementTree tutorial, specifically the section titled "Modifying an XML file".  https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file

Comment: Aside: I find [lxml](http://lxml.de/) more useful when modifying XML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that using ElementTree. The `.remove()` function can delete XML elements from an XML tree. Here is an example of how to remove all videos named `name2` from the XML file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('in.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

items_to_delete = root.findall("./video[title='name2']")
for item in items_to_delete:
    root.remove(item)

tree.write('out.xml')
```

Reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file